# Is it possible to upload photo on twitter ? if yes then How to post or upload photo from android?

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter, android-emulator, android-widget

I am new to integrate twitter in android. In My application i want to upload the photo on the twitter.

I am not sure how its possible but i found to upload the photo option during tweet on the twitter site. So i want to Upload the Photo in that tweets.

Is there any Example or demo to integrate this ?
Please Give me link to any demo project or example.
Thanks.

Update:

After twit4j implement get error like this:

```
11-12 10:36:19.384: WARN/System.err(283): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
11-12 10:36:19.394: WARN/System.err(283):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:553)
11-12 10:36:19.404: WARN/System.err(283):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:483)
11-12 10:36:19.404: WARN/System.err(283):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:320)
11-12 10:36:19.416: WARN/System.err(283):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:277)
11-12 10:36:19.416: WARN/System.err(283):     at com.harrison.lee.twitpic4j.ResponseXMLParser.parseResponse(ResponseXMLParser.java:81)
11-12 10:36:19.416: WARN/System.err(283):     at com.harrison.lee.twitpic4j.TwitPic.uploadAndPost(TwitPic.java:170)
11-12 10:36:19.416: WARN/System.err(283):     at com.example.drawing.DrawingActivity.onClick(DrawingActivity.java:408)
11-12 10:36:19.424: WARN/System.err(283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 10:36:19.424: WARN/System.err(283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-12 10:36:19.424: WARN/System.err(283):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
11-12 10:36:19.435: WARN/System.err(283):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-12 10:36:19.435: WARN/System.err(283):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-12 10:36:19.435: WARN/System.err(283):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-12 10:36:19.483: WARN/System.err(283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 10:36:19.483: WARN/System.err(283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-12 10:36:19.483: WARN/System.err(283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-12 10:36:19.483: WARN/System.err(283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 10:36:19.483: WARN/System.err(283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-12 10:36:19.494: WARN/System.err(283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-12 10:36:19.494: WARN/System.err(283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-12 10:36:19.494: WARN/System.err(283):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 10:36:19.494: INFO/System.out(283): Status: null
11-12 10:36:19.506: INFO/System.out(283): Status Id: null
11-12 10:36:19.506: INFO/System.out(283): User Id: null
11-12 10:36:19.506: INFO/System.out(283): Media Aid: null
11-12 10:36:19.506: INFO/System.out(283): Media Url: null
11-12 10:36:19.514: INFO/System.out(283): Error Code: null
11-12 10:36:19.514: INFO/System.out(283): Error Msg: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need a jar file twitpic4j.jar

http://code.google.com/p/twitpic4j/downloads/detail?name=twitpic4j.jar&can=2&q=

Here is the code; please be sure that you have registered your twitter account with the tweetpic account.

```
File file = ***YOUR IMAGE***

TwitPic tpRequest = new TwitPic(this.username, this.password);
TwitPicResponse tpResponse = null;
// Make request and handle exceptions                           
try {
        tpResponse = tpRequest.uploadAndPost(file, this.tweet);
        return "s";
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TwitPicException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Here, this.username and this.password is static value ?

Comment: I mean user have to enter the username and password every time ?

Comment: I have use your code. But after using it. I got error. And there is no image uploded to the twitter. Please see updated question for error log.

Comment: username/password - it depends entirely upon the requirement of your application. this.tweet here is a string you'd like to to tweet.
I am not sure what is happening...works like a charm everytime i use it..

Comment: Ok but is this.username and this.password is set by developer ?

Comment: no it is the username/password of the twitter account in which the image will be uploaded. In my case i had a login page where the user entered his username/password and then uploaded his images...

Comment: Whats more u have done instead of this code ? I mean do you have twitter application in your device ?

Comment: comment out the return "s" part. that was part of my program flow.

Comment: Ok. Now i got the error. User must have to registered with the tweetpic account. And then with that id and passward he/she is able to upload the image and text on the tweeter account.

Comment: I got the answer and Solution. But still want to know is there any other way to do it. I mean i want to do it same like facebook. where we dont have to give username and password. and if the user is not login then it will autometicaly open its inbuilt webView to login in twitter and and then post tweet.

Comment: I am not sure if there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

Yup,It is possible.
I have used **[Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)** library to integrate Twitter in My Apps.

you can get to know the classes provide here,**[JavaDoc](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/index.html)**

Comment: Please see Updated question. I got error to implement the tweet4j.